# Dash Errors while trying to create a table using Multiple Output Options

Tags: python, pandas, plotly-dash

I am trying to create dash table on Web using Inputs. However the issue is that the data is created from database from the callback and a priori, 
I do not know the names of the columns unless the pandas dataframeis created using the callback function. 
I have checked that I getting correct data. However not able to display it. I have used multiple output options (using Dash 0.41)

My code looks as follows: ( I have not provided the details of the function which generates the pandas dataframe in the callback **someFunc**, 
as that was not important for the purpose of this Dash code TroubleShooting.

```
 import dash_table as dt

 def someFunc(ID, pattern_desc, file_path):

       ## do something 
      return df # pandas dataframe
```

#

```
 external_stylesheets = ['https://codepen.io/chriddyp/pen/bWLwgP.css']

 app = dash.Dash(__name__, external_stylesheets=external_stylesheets)

 server = app.server

 app = dash.Dash(__name__)

 app.config.suppress_callback_exceptions = True
 app.css.config.serve_locally = True
 app.scripts.config.serve_locally = True


 app.layout = html.Div(
      children = [
      html.Div(
      id = 'title',
      children = appTitle,
      className = 'titleDiv'  
   ),
 html.Div(
    children = [
        html.Div(
            children = "Enter ID:",
            className = 'textDiv'
        ),
        dcc.Input(
            id = 'ID',
            type = 'text',
            value = 'ABCER1',
            size = 8),

        html.Div(
            children = "Enter Test Pattern",
            className = 'textDiv'
        ),
        dcc.Input(
            id = 'pattern_desc',
            type = 'text',
            value = 'Sample',
            size = 20),

         html.Div(
            children = "Enter File OutPut Path:",
            className = 'textDiv'
        ),
        dcc.Input(
            id = 'file_path',
            type = 'text',
            value = '',
            size = 30),

        html.Button(
            id = 'submit',
            n_clicks = 0,
            children = 'Search'
        )
    ]
),

    html.Div(
        id = 'tableDiv',
        children = dash_table.DataTable(
        id = 'table',
        style_table={'overflowX': 'scroll'},
        style_as_list_view=True,
        style_header={'backgroundColor': 'white','fontWeight': 
            'bold'},
         ),
        className = 'tableDiv'
    )
  ]
)

  # callback to update the table
  @app.callback([Output('table', 'data'),Output('table', 'columns')]
          [Input('submit', 'n_clicks')],
          [State('ID', 'value'),  State('pattern_desc', 'value'), 
        State('file_path', 'value')])
   def update_table(n_clicks, ID, pattern_desc, file_path):

         df = someFunc(ID, pattern_desc, file_path)
    mycolumns = [{'name': i, 'id': i} for i in df.columns]
        return html.Div([
                dt.DataTable(
            id='table',
            columns=mycolumns,
            data=df.to_dict("rows")
         )
        ])
```

So in this case the function **someFunc** which takes the 3 input arguments returns a pandas dataframe which can have different columns based on the inputs. Thus the app layout should display
those columns as given by the output of the callback function dynamically based on the inputs.
I should be getting the webpage populated with table and columns, But instead getting an error.   When I run this, I am getting the data generated through the function to the file, but dash is not able to 
generated the table on webpage. I get the following error:

**dash.exceptions.InvalidCallbackReturnValue: The callback ..table.data...table.columns.. is a multi-output.
Expected the output type to be a list or tuple but got Div([DataTable(columns=[{'name': 'pattern_desc', 'id': 'pattern_desc'}, ......**

Not Sure How I can achieve that. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Same question exactly has already been asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55801796/how-can-we-create-data-columns-in-dash-table-dynamically-using-callback-with-a-f/55801875?noredirect=1#comment98272527_55801875).

Comment: Thanks. But still did not get any appropriate answer. Looking to get the code working.

Answer (score 3):

The error message is fairly straightforward. The decorator

```
`@app.callback([Output('table', 'data'),
 Output('table', 'columns')], ...)`
```

specifies 2 outputs so the function should return a tuple `(data, columns)` rather than a `html.Div(...)` value.

Comment: When returning properties Dash expects the return value to always be a tuple, even if there is only one property.

Answer (score 0):

What Yixing said above is correct - so if you want to just return the data and columns to the `table` Datatable your return statement should just be `df.to_dict("rows"), mycolumns`.
If you want to keep the return statement the way you have it now, then change your decorator to be

```
`@app.callback(Output('tableDiv', 'children'),
          [Input('submit', 'n_clicks')],
          [State('ID', 'value'),
           State('pattern_desc', 'value'), 
           State('file_path', 'value')])`
```

I would say the first option is preferable.